# Ubuntu 18.10 freezes after login

Tags: lenovo, 18.10

I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my Lenovo IdeaPad 720s (Intel Core i5-8250U CPU) and everything was working fine. Then I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 and now, I'm having a problem where it keeps freezing after login and it becoming entirely unresponsive. Does anybody else has a similar problem?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**UPDATED:** The problem was fixed after reinstalled Ubuntu 18.10. Now  everything is working fine but I couldn't figure out what even happened. Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: appindicatorsupport is in there for me. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well when installing on my Lenovo YOGA 720 . In my case, i re-installed but this time choosing the "minimal" install rather than the normal one initially offerered.. I then immediately apt updated and set up the graphics card. So far it seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: may i know how you set the graphics card ?

Comment: To update, i just re-installed afresh when the new Ubuntu 19.04 came out and did not have to do anything for the graphics card to work.

Comment: did you also checked the option that states install additional proprietary driver at the step just before selecting partition while installing ?

Comment: @HarshGundecha , yep, I always opt for installing additional proprietary drivers,and i carry out the install online (adding wifi) so I get the latest packages. When I launch the Software Updater app, it says I'm `Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-418 (proprietary, tested)`.

Comment: tired that too that even on mint 19 but no luck, seems that AMD is the issue here, would have been better if i had NVIDIA